# Cakephp hanging after post request via httpsocket containing json data

Tags: php, json, cakephp, post

at the moment I am fighting with a http post request within cakePHP.

I am using the code below to communicate with an external API that requires Authorization.
The problem is, as soon as I add the body with the JSON context, the whole application is hanging.  It's loading forever in the browser, not coming back with any results. Have to stop and start Apache to come back to normal. Tested on different machines, same effect.
If I don't send the (JSON) body, I am getting obviously a 500 server error, but it's telling me that the authorization is working otherwise I would get an unauthorized.
If I do a "GET" request to the same API, it's working fine and coming back with a result.
The JSON syntax is clean, if I process the variable and the other information using an API tester it's working (https://apigee.com/console).

UPDATE: It is working if the request is valid. However, on the API tester it's giving me a "400 Bad Request". I would need to handle that within my application but in this case the situation described above is happening. Expectation would be that it's returning the error.

```
$options = array( 
        'body' => $json_order,
        'header' => array(  
        'Authorization' =>'123456',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        ),

    );

    $result=$HttpSocket->post('https://<address>',null,$options);
    debug($HttpSocket->request);
```

same effect if I would do it the other way

```
$options = array( 
        'header' => array(  
        'Authorization' =>'123456',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        ),

    );

    $result=$HttpSocket->post('https://<address>',$json_order,$options);
    debug($HttpSocket->request);
```

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Comment: I really don't get your update? o_O Have you checked your server logs? Also please supply a complete working example (that is including all data, and if possible also the API URL). ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: I am using cakePHP 2.5.6. To give you more details on the update: I tried to place a order for a product below the product price so there is a "bad request" send back. In this case the whole application gets stuck. I am investigating if that is a problem on the far end (not under my control). If other things are done that cause a "bad request" it's working and I can display the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

To clear that up: The problem was on the far end not responding correctly with an error code. =